# Flutter ElevatedButton not enabled while using onPressed

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I am learning flutter/dart.  I am not sure why, but when testing my code in code studio,  my buttons are not enabled.  they are dark and unclickable. I have been trying different things, but it feels like the "onPressed" functions are not working.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  void answerQuestion() {
    print('Answer chosen!');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext cntx) {
    var questions = [
      'What\'s your favorite color?',
      'What\'s your favorite animal?',
    ];
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('My First App'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Text('The question!'),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('Answer 1'),
              onPressed: answerQuestion,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('Answer 2'),
              onPressed: () => print('Answer 2 chosen!'),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('Answer 3'),
              onPressed: () {
                //...
                print('Answer 3 chosen');
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
`
```

Comment: I've just tested your code which is perfectly working!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code works fine, just make sure hot reload/restart is working

Comment: Yes, I rebooted my emulator and its working just fine

Answer (score -1):

I rebooted my emulator and it's working like a charm!  please archive this question